# No signature of method: com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.getNdkFolder()

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I found different answers relating to this issue but non worked for me, so am not sure if I have added something wrong somewhere.

Error:

Gradle sync failed: No signature of method: com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.getNdkFolder() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

**build.gradle module**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.domain.game'
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 11

        ndk {
            moduleName "cocos2dcpp_shared"
        }

        sourceSets.main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
            java.srcDirs += '../../Classes'
            assets.srcDirs = ['../../Resources']
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}


task buildNative(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
    def ndkDir = project.plugins.findPlugin('com.android.application').getNdkFolder()
    //def ndkDir = project.plugins.findPlugin('com.android.application').getNdkFolder()
    if(Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS))
        commandLine "${ndkDir}\\ndk-build.cmd",'-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath, '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(), 'all'
    else
        commandLine "${ndkDir}/ndk-build",'-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath, '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(), 'all'
}

task cleanNative(type: Exec, description: 'Clean JNI object files') {
    def ndkDir = project.plugins.findPlugin('com.android.application').getNdkFolder()
    if(Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS))
        commandLine "${ndkDir}\\ndk-build.cmd",'-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath, 'clean'
    else
        commandLine "${ndkDir}/ndk-build",'-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath, 'clean'
}

clean.dependsOn 'cleanNative'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn buildNative
}


dependencies {
    compile project(':googleplayservices_lib')
    compile files('libs/OpenIAB-0.9.6-sync2.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/GiftizSDK_1.5.0.jar')
}
```

**build.gradle project**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Thu Apr 06 06:38:18 BST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Update:

**local.properties**

```
ndk.dir=C\:\\AndroidEclipse\\android-ndk-r10e
sdk.dir=C\:\\AndroidEclipse\\SDK
```

It fails on this line **def ndkDir = project.plugins.findPlugin('com.android.application').getNdkFolder()**

Answer (score 1):

use `plugins.getPlugin('com.android.application').sdkHandler.ndkFolder` or `android.ndkDirectory` instead.

Comment: I already tried this but it didn't event detect it starting from the begining "plugins". It's like plugin does not exist as part of the available [options](https://snag.gy/LYkpqZ.jpg).

Same issue with **android.ndkDirectory**. android is there but ndkDirectory is not

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover `android.ndkDirectory` work for me. we're using the same gradle version 2.3.0. Or you can try this below. `def androidPluginExtension = project.getExtensions().getByName("android");
    // Use this for easily viewing the properties available in the extension.
    androidPluginExtension.properties.each { Object key, Object value ->
        System.out.println("Extensionprop: ${key} ${value}")
    }
    String ndkDir2 = androidPluginExtension.getProperties().get("ndkDirectory");
    System.out.println("Using ndk dir: ${ndkDir2}");`